# Как установить php 5.5 на centos 7

Tags: php, centos, vps

Купил VPS. Стоит CENTOS 7 + VestaCP. Мне нужно изменить версию на php 5.5. Как мне это сделать? Пробовал следующие инструкции:
https://linux-notes.org/ustanovka-php-5-4-php-5-5-php-5-6-na-centos-redhat-fedora/
http://blog.sedicomm.com/2017/12/06/kak-ustanovit-php-5-4-5-6-na-centos-6/
[image: Многое перепробовал]

Comment: Вопрос чисто ради интереса: вам такой контраст глаза не выедает?)

Comment: Я на Debian настраивал по [инструкции](https://blog.vpsville.ru/blog/howto/222.html), думаю на CentOS не сильно будет отличаться.